# Django FileField not working with german "Umlaut" (ä, ö, ü)

Tags: django, character-encoding, filefield

I use django, nginx and gunicorn.

In my models i have a FileField which is not working with german "Umlaute" in production.

When i try to upload  a file (select file and push "save") in /admin with an "Umlaut":

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe4' in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

models.py

```
class wiki(models.Model):

    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

On the development Web server on the local machine (./manage runserver) it  is working fine, so i thought it has something to do with gunicorn or nginx and did the following changes without success:

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:

(added --env LANG=de_DE.UTF-8)

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=django
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/opt/django/project
ExecStart=/opt/django/bin/python3 /opt/django/bin/gunicorn --env LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 --workers 3 --bind unix:/opt/django/gunicorn.sock uhd.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain

```
server {
    charset UTF-8;
}
```

Here are some information which i think might be useful:

$ locale

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

cat /etc/*-release

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

i appreciate any help. If more informations are needed, please let me know.

Comment: Python 2.x right? `def __str__(self):` should be `def __unicode__(self):`

Comment: actually it's Python 3.5.3 in developement and Python 3.4.2 in production.

Comment: I never get why developers want to use two different Pythons for prd and dev. In your case it isn't likely to be related to your issue. But it is bad practice. It isn't hard to have multiple Pythons installed. So it isn't hard to keep development and production **exactly** the same.

Comment: That's why i upgraded my production and it seems to fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded from Debian Jessie (oldstable) to Debian Stretch (stable) and now everything is working.

Python was upgraded from Python 3.4.2 to Python 3.5.3.
$ locale still gives the same output, gunicorn and nginx are still the same as shown in the question.

$ cat /etc/*-release

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```